# How to avoid repeating Allow/Deny access control statements across multiple Directory directives in Apache2 VirtualHosts?

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost

On Apache2, I have a VirtualHost with a number of `<Directory>` directives/sections containing multiple access control statements

i.e.

```
<Directory /foo>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from ...
    Allow from ...
    ...
</Directory>
...
```

Is there a way to specify the access control at a higher level (above `<Directory>`)? Or should I be using macros?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you can just specify a <Directory ...> directive for the highest level folder appropriate, even if it's your web-root (i.e. set it in the 'default' conf file for localhost)

Comment: But what if the <Directory> directives have no common parent folder?

Comment: like I said you can apply the appropriate configuration / directives directly on your 'localhost' (i.e. domain/web-root) -- what OS are you running, if Linux then prob /var/www is your web-root, you can use a .htaccess file or edit your 'default' vhost config for localhost!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question, you're looking for a way to apply a set of allow/deny restrictions to a set of directories that may not share a common parent.

You can place all your allow/deny directives into a separate file (call it, say, `/etc/httpd/conf.d/accesslist`, or whatever makes sense in your distribution), and then using the `Include` directory to include those rules where appropriate:

```
<Directory /some/directory>
  Include /etc/httpd/conf.d/accesslist
</Directory>

<Directory /another/directory>
  Include /etc/httpd/conf.d/accesslist
</Directory>
```

But if your directories all share a common configuration, you can use something like `mod_macro` to create a reusable template with variable substitution.